# File position and word splitter

Tags: python

I have a program that

- Takes a text file with several sentences
- Asks the user if they want to compress/decompress the file.
- If Compress is chosen, the sentence will have all the unique words and the positions of these words needed to recreate the sentence again.
- If decompress is chosen, the compressed text file will need to be found and using the position list given and the unique words - decompressed - the several sentences in the files need to be on separate lines.

Here is the code I have managed to create. It is a subroutine and it's rather faulty.

```
uniqueWords = []
positions = []
file = 

def valChoice():
    choice = (" ")
    while choice not in ["compress", "decompress"]:
        choice = input("Choose compress or decompress").lower()
        if choice not in ["compress", "decompress"]:
            print("Please input compress or decompress")
    finalChoice = valChoice()


if finalChoice = ("compress"):
    print("This where i get confused..")


elif finalChoice = ("decompress"):
    print("This where i get confused..")
```

What is wrong with this code? How can I fix it?

Comment: This question is too broad for SO's typical Q&A format.  We look for a specific programming problem, rather than a request for wholesale design.  Now, if you can outline the algorithm for compression and decompression, try to write the code, and come back with a specific problem in the implementation, we're exactly what you need.

Comment: By the way, "Green Eggs and Ham" makes a nice, larger test case for this program.  It has a vocabulary of only 50 words, the result of a bet between Theodore Geisl (Dr. Seuss) and Bennett Cerf (founder of Random House Publishing)

Comment: Hi!  Yes that is the level of help I need right now. I don't know if a dictionary at this point is needed or not, with just a list of all the unique words and the order of which these unique words need to be in to recreate the sentence on the text file. For the decompression part I am completely stumped as it takes the unique words and positions from the compressed file and makes them into the original sentence and saves it back on a file. As for the algorithims, I can give it a shot later on in the day!

Comment: @KellyBanks Please don't vandalize your posts. Is there a problem?

Answer (score 1):

With my caveat above, I'll take a shot at what I think you're asking.

To compress the file, iterate through the input words.  Store each word reference in a dictionary: the word itself is the key, and its position is the value.  If the word is already in the dictionary, then add the new position reference to the existing list of references.

Decompression works in reverse: make a sequence of positions and words.  Sort that sequence into ascending order.  Concatenate the words to make the original text.

Is that the level of help you need right now?

Comment: In case you have follow-up questions, I prepared by writing some code to do the job as I outlined it.